# How can I add HTML to this Knockout.js Viewmodel variable?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-components, knockout-templating

I have a list of steps displayed on the page. Some steps (*but not all*) will have 1-3 substeps. I was thinking the simplest way of doing this was to just write the HTML manually within each step declaration in the viewmodel.

If you look in the code below, what I want to do is something like:

```
this.sidebarStepModel1 = new SidebarStepModel();
this.sidebarStepModel1.message("step 2 <ul><li>substep 1</li><li>substep2</li></ul>");
```

The problem is, HTML written in there is interpreted as a `string` and not as `HTML`. How can I make it so that it interprets the HTML as actual HTML?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8o31m6rq/2/

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <sidebar-step params="vm: sidebarStepModel0"></sidebar-step>
    <sidebar-step params="vm: sidebarStepModel1"></sidebar-step>
    <sidebar-step params="vm: sidebarStepModel2"></sidebar-step>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript/Knockout:**

```
//custom element <sidebar-step>
ko.components.register("sidebar-step", {
    synchronous: true,
    viewModel: function (params) {
        this.vm = params.vm;
    },

    template: "<li data-bind='text: vm.message'>vm.onChangeElement</li>"
});

// model
var SidebarStepModel = function () {
    this.message = ko.observable("step description");
};

// viewmodel
var OrderGuideViewModel = function () {

    this.sidebarStepModel0 = new SidebarStepModel();
    this.sidebarStepModel0.message("step 1");

    this.sidebarStepModel1 = new SidebarStepModel();
    this.sidebarStepModel1.message("step 2");

    this.sidebarStepModel2 = new SidebarStepModel();
    this.sidebarStepModel2.message("step 3");
};

ko.applyBindings(new OrderGuideViewModel());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the [`html` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html) instead of the `text` binding:

```
template: "<li data-bind='html: vm.message'>vm.onChangeElement</li>"
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x27rdbmz/1/)

Comment: Well that was simple... I had no idea. Ty